# Ibm Web Aplication Server 7 publishing issue

Tags: websphere, publishing, ibm-rad

My application is a combination of Spring/Hibernate/JPA. Recently my development environment was migrated to RAD 7 with WAS7. Previous I was using v.6 for RAD & WAS.

The problem is,

when I make a **Java** change, the server publishes for a long time, sometimes it takes upto 10 mins for a single line of change to take effect. Also even JSP changes alone takes much time during publishing!!

This was not the case in WAS6. Publishing java changes was not even a concern in WAS6. The changes takes effect immediately as the publish process is done within a few seconds.

This publishing process keeps on running several times as I make changes in my code, and I have to wait (for long intervals during work hours) till it completes, to verify/test my changes during runtime. This is horrible!!

Is there a way to make WAS7 publish JSP/Java changes faster in few seconds as like WAS6? Is there any fix/refresh pack for this?

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: You should look for RAD patches if you haven't done so. Also, if it really is RAD 7.0, that's very old. 8.0 is current, 7.5 before that. Both support WAS 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be overcome if you have the control to publish rather than automatically publishing it. You can wait to make all your changes and then publish it.
To do that

In the server view double click on the server that you are working on and under publishing check the option "Never publish automatically".
Also if you can give the option "Run server with resources within the workspace" that would do reduce the time of copying the files from your workspace to server space while publishing.